# /dʒ/ sound in engineer and job

Tags: pronunciation

Why /dʒ/ sound in **engineer** and **job** is so different.

The example for **engineer**, its sound likely  /ʒ/ than /dʒ/

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/engineer

The example for **job**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/job

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same given the different contexts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I pronounce it the same in both words. What kind of English speaker have you heard to pronounce it differently?

Comment: @KateBunting When I say *engine*, the /d/ is much weaker than in *job*.